# how to draw circle by pressing the button in android

Tags: java, android, button, draw

I want to draw small circles when user presses the button.
And to that circles be in some order, **not** one on another so you can not see how many circles you made.

```
Button draw = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonOne);
draw.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        new MyView(MainActivity.this);
    }
});

public class MyView extends View {
   public MyView(Context context) {
       super(context);
       // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
   }
}


@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    int x = getWidth();
    int y = getHeight();
    int radius;
    radius = 100;
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    canvas.drawPaint(paint);
    // Use Color.parseColor to define HTML colors
    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#CD5C5C"));
    canvas.drawCircle(x / 2, y / 2, radius, paint);

}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing your original post with any new information you have will bump it to the top of the active queue.